# Disabled dedicated GPU powers on after suspend

Tags: nvidia, suspend, power-management, battery, hybrid-graphics

I have a laptop with integrated AMD graphics and discrete Nvidia GTX 1650Ti.

```
$ sudo lspci
...
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
...
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c7)
```

Ubuntu version: 21.04

Kernel: 5.11.0-17-generic

I use

```
$ sudo prime-select intel
```

to disable Nvidia Graphics and also set PCI power management to auto using TLP:

```
$ sudo tlp-stat
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control = auto (0x030000, VGA compatible controller, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/power/control = auto (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
```

This works great, the GPU is in low power mode and battery life is good:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power_state
D3cold
```

But after I use suspend the GPU starts to consume more power again:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power_state
D0
```

Please help. This thing halves my laptop's battery life.

**EDIT**: This also seems to happen randomly during laptop being on sometimes. Any ideas on what can be causing this?

Comment: Perhaps you should use Nvidia X Server Settings to select the intended profile instead of messing with TLP.

Comment: @ChanganAuto You mean the setting where you can select NVIDIA (Performance Mode), NVIDIA (On-Demand) or Intel (Power Saving Mode)? If so, than it's the same as setting profile through `prime-select` which I described above. Unfortunately this by itself doesn't put the GPU in D3 power state. The only way I managed to achieve that is by simultaneously setting GPU power profile to Intel and also setting PCI device power management to auto.

Comment: Probably you forgot to reboot after selecting the profile. Doing that enables the selected profile, it's (still) not automatic as in Windows. The power saving mode enables the iGPU ONLY and it doesn't re-enable the dGPU when waking up from suspension or rebooting.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I've rebooted my PC after changing profiles, and everything works fine until I suspend. After suspend it shows power_state D0 and starts consuming more battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD** Found [system76-power](https://github.com/pop-os/system76-power). It works perfectly for me.

Old solution:

Turns out, that removing pci device does the job:

```
prime-select intel
```

Reboot and then

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/remove'
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.1/remove'
```

This isn't perfect because reenabling the iGPU requires 2 reboots.